# How do we include files in Orbeon 4.1?

Tags: upgrade, orbeon

We are (attempting to) upgrade from Orbeon 3.9 to Orbeon 4.1.  This is NOT "Orbeon Forms", but rather an application written in the Orbeon language.

Everything was working in 3.9.
After upgrading, and changing page-flow.xml among a few other items, we found that instances brought in through includes were not being "seen", and we'd get "instance not found" warnings.

Previously, we used just:

```
<xi:include href="oxf:///apps/includes/ONHeader.xhtml"/>
```

Through experimentation, we discovered we needed to change the file to:

```
<xi:include href="oxf:///apps/includes/ONHeader.xhtml"
            xpointer="xpath(/*/*)"/>
```

(note that some xpath expressions, such as `//*`, would result in "Duplicate instance ID" error messages)

We have 2,000+ include-references, any are finding other things as well (eg. a namespace declared in the including-file must be re-declared in the in the included file)

Is this something that should be necessary? If not, how do we avoid it?

Comment: Do you mean 4.1 or 4.10, by the way? 4.1 dates back to April 18, 2013 while 4.10 is our latest release from August 26, 2015.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that this is because in the included file you had a "foreign" root element. I.e. if you were to copy-pasted the content of the included file where the `<xi:include>` was, you'd get the same problem, which sounds very much like the issue [Henry is describing in another thread](http://discuss.orbeon.com/Why-the-login-page-can-not-load-Xincludes-element-td4660654.html).

The right thing to do would be to either:

1. Remove the foreign element in the included files (moving the namespace declarations its child element.
2. Add an `xpointer="xpath(/*/*)"` to the `<xi:include>`, as you suggested.

I think that number 1 is cleaner, but I understand it is more work than adding an attribute on the `<xi:include>`.

Regarding namespaces declared in the including-file having to be re-declared in the included-file, each file should be valid XML on its own, and if a namespace is used in a file (even if in attribute), it must be declared there. Maybe you're having to make this change because in the past Orbeon Forms was incorrectly putting namespace declarations from the including file in-scope for XML in the included file, and since then that issue has been corrected.

I understand that doing those changes "isn't fun", but will make your code cleaner. And of course, if you feel that you need to make any change to get around a new bug in Orbeon Forms, rather than make changes because of bugs that have been fixed, please let us know!